# Removing the unwanted data from Scattered plot using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I want to keep the portion in the
black and remove all the other data .how can i do so please help me here.

Comment: I hope you understand we need more than a picture. Else my advice is to remove it using Paint 

Comment: Figure out a way to filter the original data, then create the chart on that new set. Having said that, I stand by the principle that data doesn't lie. Graphically the data suggest some type of binomial pattern. Filtering the data would cause a different conclusion (that there is no relationship between the X-Y axis). Your going to have to justify to whomever why the data was removed from the analysis.